# Learning Project Management

Tags: pmp, learning, pmi-framework

I have been greatly interested in becoming a Project Manager as a career path for some time. I have the current Pmbok Guide and am trying to work through several online classes. At my current employment there in no project management structure used (It is off site at the corporate level). I however specifically work on various tasks, which all qualify by definition of "Projects" as outlined in the Pmbok Guide.

My question is how can I bring in the practices of "Project Management" in to my work, considering there is no current frame work. I am hoping I can do this so I can increase the amount of tasks I can bring to completion and gain some practical knowledge to carry forward as I prepare to earn a PMP.

Comment: Welcome to PMSE. Unfortunately, your question is too broad for this site. There are too many possible answers and good answers would be too long for this format.

Comment: By the way, you can't earn a PMP without three years of actual project management practice.

Comment: The question asks how to apply PM techniques (and which) if the organisation does not provide any rules / guidelines / framework / etc. supporting PM work. It might be really broad but is also really interesting.

Comment: Sergey- You need three years of work on projects. You do not have to be the project manager or hold a project manager title. You have to have been doing project work just not have to be THE project manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've already identified a way to identify your work as 'projects'. Once you've done that, it should be easy to work PM techniques and tools into your work, although you might have to do it on your own time. You can find a bunch of templates at [ProjectManagement.com](http://www.projectmanagement.com/Templates/) for the main documents. Don't get caught up in them too much though: use what you need, and no more. the PMBOK lays out a ton of best practices and useful techniques, but most projects don't use all of them, and many smaller projects hardly use any. Take what you get use out of and leave the rest for later.

Here's a quick example: You're tasked with buying a new router, configuring it, and hooking it up. Build a quick project plan that includes a scope document, a schedule, and a WBS. Measure as you go and compare that to the plan you created.

One of the best things you could do is find a contact in your company who is at this off-site location and ask them to help you learn more about project management. A good way to do this can be to explain your intent to learn and offer to "help", that is, ask them if there are any tasks that you could do for them. People tend to respond warmly when you ask them to help you learn something that they are interested in and experienced at.

By the way, you should consider the CAPM. It could be useful for an entry level PM position to show you're interested in learning. A PMP is specifically for experienced PMs and you will have a tough time passing the exam, not to mention meeting the criteria, if you haven't managed projects before.